# Converting Apple app to Windows app

Tags: windows, file, file-conversion, ios

Is there any way to convert .ipa file to .exe or other windows application file? I looked for some converters, but I didn´t found any...

Comment: The CPU, OS API and the structure of the executable are different so no way

Comment: You should know that executables can't just be converted like you convert music. If you create and compile a program it's bound to the OS it was built for and sometimes even to the computer built on. (although there are some exceptions, like Java)

Comment: Maybe there is a chance if you have the source code for the Apple app.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to convert .ipa file to .exe or other windows application file.

To port program to other OS you need rewrite source code of program and compile it on target OS.

Really, just try find analog of you program on Windows OS.